# MS Outlook Calendar with color categories sync to iPhone

Tags: ms-office, calendar, ical, exchange-activesync, exchange

I have a problem with the iPhone calendar and the Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync calendar category colors.

Is there a app which is compatible with the MS Exchange category colors?

I understand that in apples view each calendar must have an color.
But for my plans I need no color for a calendar... I need colors for the categories and I must set them, too.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I spoke to an Apple Supervisor today who confirmed that the iPhone iOS currently is not set up to enable one to have different color categories for different types of appointments in a single calendar, but he agreed that it is a good idea. He said the best way of increasing the likelihood that Apple will make this enhancement is to go to www.apple.com/feedback and to make this enhancement request. He said the more people that ask for it the greater the likelihood Apple will make the modification. So please go to www.apple.com/feedback and request this enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

We use categories to register labour types for our project software and project billing. With Apple's mail it is indeed not possible. You can register categories using OWA, which is an app from Microsoft available thru Apple's appstore at no charge. But it requires of course an Exchange environment accessible through an URL. URL-s of apps: [iphone](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/owa-for-iphone/id659503543?mt=8), [ipad](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/owa-for-ipad/id659524331?mt=8)

Comment: I use categories, too. But for calendar instead mails.
The "OWA" App is no option for me because its need an iPhone 4S or higher. The problem iPhone is the iPhone 4.

But thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi PatrickB, i've checked with collegeaus but it seems that on iPhone 4 you have to resort to owa in the browser. Lookeeloo is an app that also supports more functions that apple calendar with exchange But I don't recall it doing categories.

Comment: Thanks but the lookeeloo app doesnt support any colors, i think.

I dont know why there is no solution for this problem!? -.-

Comment: Yep. Don't know. Maybe Microsoft likes everyone to buy a new iPhone :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a fudge but it works; you need the [WeekCal](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/weekcal-fully-unlocked/id1437153734) app.

WeekCal syncs with Exchange and has a feature where you can set a rule to apply selected colours to created or imported events. For example I use red for medical appointments in exchange and type `rz` somewhere in the location.  The rule I have set up in WeekCal is any event with `rz` anywhere in the location field is coloured red.  Easy.